# jQuery DataTables does not show Unicode characters

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jQuery DataTables to show pagination data from MySQL database.

When I show normal characters in this table, it shows proper data in table. But, when I save Unicode characters it only shows `?` characters.

The following is my html codes for this page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Township</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/styles/township.css" />"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset = "utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset = "utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset = "utf8" >

//Plug-in to fetch page data 
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnPagingInfo = function ( oSettings )
{
    return {
        "iStart":         oSettings._iDisplayStart,
        "iEnd":           oSettings.fnDisplayEnd(),
        "iLength":        oSettings._iDisplayLength,
        "iTotal":         oSettings.fnRecordsTotal(),
        "iFilteredTotal": oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay(),
        "iPage":          oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil( oSettings._iDisplayStart / oSettings._iDisplayLength ),
        "iTotalPages":    oSettings._iDisplayLength === -1 ?
            0 : Math.ceil( oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() / oSettings._iDisplayLength )
    };
};

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#example").dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sort": "position",
    "bStateSave": false,
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "iDisplayStart": 0,
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {

    },         
    "sAjaxSource": "springPaginationDataTables.web",
    "aoColumns": [

        { "mData": "townshipCode" },
        { "mData": "townshipName" },
        { "mData": "divisionName" },
        { "mData": "actionlink"}, 
    ]
} );

} );

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="table">
        <form:form action="" method="GET" align="center">
            <br>
            <table style="border: 3px;background: rgb(243, 244, 248); width: 90%; margin:20px auto;"><tr><td>
                <table id="example" class="display">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>Code</th>
                        <th>Township</th>
                        <th>Division</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>       
            </table>
            </td></tr></table>
            <br>
        </form:form>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My backend Java code for this table is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/springPaginationDataTables.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody String springPaginationDataTables(HttpServletRequest  request) throws IOException {

    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    if (null != request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))
        pageNumber = (Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayStart"))/10)+1;     

    Integer pageDisplayLength = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("iDisplayLength"));

    List<Township> listTownship = townshipDao.getList(pageNumber, pageDisplayLength);
    int count = townshipDao.getCount();

    JsonObject<Township> townshipJsonObject = new JsonObject<Township>();
    //Set Total display record
    townshipJsonObject.setiTotalDisplayRecords(count);
    //Set Total record
    townshipJsonObject.setiTotalRecords(count);
    townshipJsonObject.setAaData(listTownship);

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    String json2 = gson.toJson(townshipJsonObject);

    return json2;
}
```

I got the following output in Data Table which showing `?` instead of Unicode characters:

[image]

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: did you compile your java source code with UTF-8 character encoding?

Comment: Yes lan Lim. I already.

Comment: Where do you get the data from? database? csv? xml? excel?

Comment: @JuaRoAI, I get data from database and convert into JSON format and bind the table.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995559/json-character-encoding

Comment: And check this also: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3616359/who-sets-response-content-type-in-spring-mvc-responsebody

Comment: Thank you JuaRoAI. I have solved the problem by your link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995559/json-character-encoding. Thank you very much and original post.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the charset in the produces attribute like so:

@RequestMapping(value = "/springPaginationDataTables.web", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")