# json-simple utf-8 parsing in Java

Tags: java, json, parsing, utf-8

I'm trying to parse JSON using json-simple-1.1.1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException{

    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/qqqqqqqq/json"));

    String line = null;

    while((line = buff.readLine()) != null){

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = (Object) parser.parse(line);
        JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj;

        System.out.println((String)jsonObj.get("name"));
    }
}
```

My JSON source file using UTF-8 without BOM

```
{"name":"ą"}
{"name":"ć"}
{"name":"ń"}
{"name":"ź"}
{"name":"ż"}
{"name":"ó"}
```

Output from println:

```
Ä…
Ä‡
Ĺ„
Ĺş
ĹĽ
Ăł
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON character encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995559/json-character-encoding)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `FileReader` uses the default charset which must not be UTF-8.

Use

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/qqqqqqqq/json"), "UTF-8"));
```

instead.