# Jquery DataTables not able to display unicode characters.

Tags: javascript, utf-8, datatables

I have created datatables and my input JSON is in the below format.

```
[{"input" : "안녕하세요"}]
```

Since the string is in Korean language, data table is not able to load this data.
Getting below error...
Data tables warning..Requested unknown parameter...

Have tried setting `content="text/html;charset=utf-8"` in my main html page.
Nothing has worked...
Please let me know how to resolve this. Thanks.

Comment: This might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995559/json-character-encoding It suggests that the data coming back from the server isn't returned as unicode...? Datatables has no issue displaying the characters within a standard table: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/4644q44s/

Answer (score 0):

For java you can encode it like:

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchFilter.do")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getContactSearchBean(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            String clientName) {
        logger.info("Getting data  according to search filter to refresh table ");
        List<Map<String, Object>> contactDetails = service.getContactDetailSearch(request, clientName);
        JSONArray json = JSONArray.fromObject(contactDetails);
        String jsonString = json.toString();
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        logger.info("returning data for populating datatable");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonString, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: For other languages too you should set charset=utf-8 in  responseHeaders

Comment: Can you please also add a little description for less informed people like me.

Comment: UTF-8 encoding supports chinese or special character.

Comment: So if you want to display chinese characters in your datatable then you will have to encode your data in UTF-8 like this                                                           HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
 responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");                                This code will encode your response as UTF-8 in java. If you are using any other lenguage then  also you should encode your response with utf-8 encoding