# Get arabic word in ajax json in spring 3 issue

Tags: java, json, ajax, spring

I have web application written in java spring 3, i have used filter

```
<filter>
<filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
 </filter>
```

but when I get my json using ajax response. It shows '?????'. Is there anybody who have encountered similar issue. I have searched on internet but haven't got any solution.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928046/spring-mvc-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **mysql** db on your back-end ,

Just set Collation as " **utf8_general_ci** " to save your arabic data, and try it again.

Comment: yes i have set **utf8_general_ci** collation, and data also saved in arabic in database

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995559/json-character-encoding  See if this helps