# JSON String with Special Characters

Tags: java, json

When I am trying to send the JSON string `{"value" : "aériennes"}` from one service to other it's throwing me following exception:

```
Could not read JSON document: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x62
```

I have tried all the things showed in this URL:
[JSON character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995559/json-character-encoding)

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: I suspect the problem is somewhere in either the sending or receiving code - but you haven't shown us *any* code, so we don't know what either the sender or receiver looks like.

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow for this problem. here is one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352861/jackson-jsonparseexception-invalid-utf-8-middle-byte

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Also check your file encoding `System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));` I suspect it is something else.